# Cannot deserialize xml string to the extended genericType's Object using xstream

Tags: java, generics, xstream

First,I want to show my Core code for deserialize the xml String

```
    public XMLClient<T> xmlToClient(String xmlString,T t) throws Exception{
    //according to the generic class's name,insert the name after input tag
    //to make the xstream to know which class is going to deserialize to
        String insertClassName = t.getGenericTypeRecord();
        xmlString.replaceAll("<INPUT>", "<INPUT input."+insertClassName+">");
        XMLClient<T> xmlClient = new XMLClient<T>();
        XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xs.processAnnotations(XMLClient.class);
        xmlClient = (XMLClient<T>)xs.fromXML(xmlString);
        logger.info(xmlString);
        return xmlClient;
    }
```

T is the a class extended from the super base class.
just like

> T extends baseInputXml

but when the application run at

```
xmlClient = (XMLClient<T>)xs.fromXML(xmlString);
```

there will be error message telling me no matching property in XMLClient.although the property does not exist in the super T class ,but exist in the child T class

I wish you could get my idea,I'm really puzzled with these genericType and xstream convert
thank you

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
xs.processAnnotations(XMLClient.class);
```

This line should be edited to

```
xs.processAnnotations(XMLClient.class);
xs.processAnnotations(XMLClientsSuperClass.class);
```